# Owl Carousel with three synced slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am searching for a solution to sync owl carousel slides.

I've already made a synced slide with only 2 slides.

What I really need is one slide which is the category, and below is the second slide which contains a variable count of content, which belongs to the different categories.

My solution was, to copy/paste the former code for two slides and change all the classes and everything. But it confuses all classes now on the different slides.

Is there another solution for this idea?

**Javascript**

```
var sync1 = $(".service-line");
var sync2 =$(".servicetext");

$(".service-line").owlCarousel({
    navigation: false,
    pagination: true,
    slideSpeed: 1000,
    paginationSpeed: 500,
    paginationNumbers: true,
    singleItem: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoHeight:false,
    animateIn: 'slideIn',
    animateOut: 'slideOut',
    afterAction : syncPosition,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
    afterMove: afterAction
});

function afterAction(){
   $( ".owl-item.active" ).find( "animation-cap" ).addClass( "animated", "bounce" );
}

$(".servicetext").owlCarousel({
     items: 1,
     pagination: false,
     slideSpeed: 800,
     paginationSpeed: 700,
     animateIn: 'slideIn',
     animateOut: 'slideOut',
     autoHeight: true,
     responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
     mouseDrag: false,
     afterInit : function(el){
         el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
     }
});

function syncPosition(el){
    var current = this.currentItem;
    $(".servicetext")
      .find(".owl-item")
      .removeClass("synced")
      .eq(current)
      .addClass("synced");
    if($(".servicetext").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
      center(current);
    }
  }

  $(".servicetext").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
  });

  function center(number){
    var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
    var num = number;
    var found = false;
    for(var i in sync2visible){
      if(num === sync2visible[i]){
        var found = true;
      }
    }

    if(found===false){
      if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+1);
      }else{
        if(num - 1 === -1){
          num = 0;
        }
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
      }
    } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1]);
    } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1);
    }

  }



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="konfig-slide-top"> <!--TOP Slider #1 -->

    <!--TOP SLIDER slide1-->
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 animation-cap">
            <h2>Category 1</h2>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <!--<img src="img/service/01.png" alt="01">-->
    </div>

  </div><!--slide1 ends-->

  <!--TOP SLIDER slide2-->
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 animation-cap">
            <h2>Category 1</h2>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <!--<img src="img/service/01.png" alt="01">-->
    </div>

  </div><!--slide2 ends-->


</div>
<!-- Top Slider ends -->


<!-- Bottom Slider Starts -->
<div class="konfig-slide-bottom">

  <!-- ======  BOTTOM SLIDER Slide 1 ====== -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row lower-input-main">
      <!-- ======  INNER SLIDER Slide starts ====== -->
      <div class="konfig-slide-bottom-inner">
        <div class="row">
          <!--inner slider slide 1 -->

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 style="color:white;">Slide 1 inner slide</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <!--slide 2 inner slide -->

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 style="color:white;">Slide 2 inner slide</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the wrong things, sorry.
At least, I tried again this morning and achieved my task. I just want to paste my code, so this question is answered.

My jquery code:

```
var synctop = $(".konfig-slide-top");
    var syncbottom =$(".konfig-slide-bottom");


    $(".konfig-slide-top").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed: 1000,
        paginationSpeed: 500,
        paginationNumbers: false,
        singleItem: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        autoHeight:false,
        animateIn: 'slideIn',
        animateOut: 'slideOut',
        afterAction : syncPositionnew,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
        afterMove: afterActionnew
    });

    $(".konfig-slide-bottom").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: false,
        slideSpeed: 800,
        paginationSpeed: 700,
        animateIn: 'slideIn',
        animateOut: 'slideOut',
        autoHeight: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
        mouseDrag: false,
        afterInit : function(el){
        el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("syncednew");
        }
    });


    var owl = $(".konfig-slide-inner");

    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: false,

        slideSpeed: 800,
        paginationSpeed: 700,
        animateIn: 'slideIn',
        animateOut: 'slideOut',
        autoHeight: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
        mouseDrag: false,
        loop: false,
        afterInit : function(el){
        el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("syncednew2");
        }
    });


    //slide inner slider        
    $('.next-inner').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
    });

    var top = $(".konfig-slide-top");

    // slide parent slider
    $('.next-top').click(function() {
        top.trigger('owl.next');
    });




    function afterActionnew(){
        $( ".owl-item.active" ).find( "animation-cap" ).addClass( "animated", "bounce" );
    }

    function syncPositionnew(el){
var current = this.currentItem;
$(".konfig-slide-bottom")
  .find(".owl-item")
  .removeClass("syncednew")
  .eq(current)
  .addClass("syncednew");
if($(".konfig-slide-bottom").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
  centernew(current);
}
  }

  $(".konfig-slide-bottom").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
synctop.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
  });

  function centernew(number){
var syncbottomvisible = syncbottom.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
var num = number;
var found = false;
for(var i in syncbottomvisible){
  if(num === syncbottomvisible[i]){
    var found = true;
  }
}

if(found===false){
  if(num>syncbottomvisible[syncbottomvisible.length-1]){
    syncbottom.trigger("owl.goTo", num - syncbottomvisible.length+1);
  }else{
    if(num - 1 === -1){
      num = 0;
    }
    syncbottom.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
  }
} else if(num === syncbottomvisible[syncbottomvisible.length-1]){
  syncbottom.trigger("owl.goTo", syncbottomvisible[1]);
} else if(num === syncbottomvisible[0]){
  syncbottom.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1);
}

 }
```

In HTML the konfig-slide-inner is nested in the konfig-slide-bottom:

```
<div class="konfig-slide-top">
-slide 1
-slide 2
- etc.
</div>

<div class="konfig-slide-bottom">
  <div class="konfig-slide-inner">
    -slide 1 
       -text 1
       -text 2
       -text 3
    -slide 2
       -text 1
       -text 2
       -text 3
    - etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have a slider with multiple slides, which is synced with the top slider.
The only problem is, that when konfig-slide-inner changes from slide1 to slide2 the text1 from slide2 is not shown, it jumps directly to text2. This summs up, so if I have a slide 3 now 2 text-slides are not shown, and so on. 
I can't get the clue of it.
Please, can anyone help me?